# Google AJAX API Loader

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem loading the Google AJAX APIs in response to user input instead of when the page loads.

This works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("search", "1");
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function() { alert("loaded"); });
</script>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clicked() {
        google.load("search", "1");
        google.setOnLoadCallback(function() { alert("loaded"); });
    }
</script>
```

The **clicked** function is a handler for a simple link.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: What exactly calls `clicked()`?

Comment: clicked() is a function called when a link is clicked. <a href="#" onclick="clicked()">Load</a>

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the link and its operation. I tested it with putting an alert call inside the clicked() function.

Comment: There must be some error message in the error console. Is there not?

Comment: In Mozilla, there isn't. In IE, it's "Object doesn't support this property or method" with nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the IE Response, it may be the case that the Google AJAX APIs haven't loaded by the time you click the button, therefore the "google" object is undefined.

Try this (http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/):

```
function mapsLoaded() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map2(document.getElementById("map"));
  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
}

function loadMaps() {
  google.load("maps", "2", {"callback" : mapsLoaded});
}

function initLoader() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABCDEFG&callback=loadMaps";
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much! It was right there in front of me in the docs and I didn't see it. And I wasn't about to look at the docs again assuming that I had already seen everything. You probably saved me HOURS of searching. Thanks again.